# Ruby on Rails: check_box_tag not saving state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, checkbox

I'm having a problem with a `check_box_tag` that I am using when trying to search for archived  projects in a table.

```
<%= hidden_field :archive, :value => false %>
<% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>
  Archive: <%= check_box_tag :archive, true, false, :class => "archive" %></H2>
<% else %>
  <%= hidden_field :archive, :value => false %>
<% end %>
```

So if the user isn't an admin, archive is always false.

If the user is an admin, then archive is always false, unless they check the checkbox.

When the check box is checked, and a search is submitted, the results are shown, but the box becomes unchecked again. Is there a way to check it checked? I tried using `:selection => params[:archive]` but that didn't seem to work. Thanks in advance.

**Adding search function**

```
def self.like(text); "%#{text}%"; end

  def self.search(search_archive, search_client)
    _projects = Project.scoped 


    if search_archive.present?
 _projects = _projects.where(:archive => search_archive)
    end
    if search_client.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['client LIKE ?', like(search_client)] 
    end


    _projects

  end


end
```

Search action:

```
def search

    @search = params[:archive], params[:client]

    @project_search = Project.search(*@search).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginated_for_index(per_page, page)

    @search_performed = !@search.reject! { |c| c.blank? }.empty? 

  @project = Project.new(params[:project])



respond_to do |format|
      format.html # search.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @project }
    end

end
```

URLS:

When I search for Client: Test, which archived checked:

```
http://localhost:3000/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&%5Bclient%5D=Test&%5D=&archive=true&per_page=10
```

No projects are found which is correct, now I unclick archived:

```
http://localhost:3000/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&%5Bclient%5D=Test&%5D=&archive%5B%7B%3Avalue%3D%3Efalse%7D%5D=&per_page=10
```

Which again shows the correct results, but the box is now checked, but should be unchecked, incase I want to refine the search

**Fix:**
In my search function:

```
if search_archive.present?
  _projects = _projects.where(:archive => search_archive == "true")
end
if !search_archive.present? 
  _projects = _projects.where(:archive => search_archive == "false")
end
```

In my search view:

```
<% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>
  Archive: <%= check_box_tag :archive, true, !!params[:archive], :class => "archive" %></H2>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<%= check_box_tag :archive, true, false, :class => "archive" %>
```

To

```
<%= check_box_tag :archive, true, !!params[:archive], :class => "archive" %>
```

Ref [`check_box_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M002246) for more information

Comment: Thanks, it  now stays true, but if I want to go back to false and click search, it searches with true, and the box stays true

Comment: You have to add boolean condition in place of `!!params[:archive]` which states that checkbox need to be checked or not. it depend on your code like "params[:archive]=='true'"

Comment: I am so confused now. I have added my search function and search action. I think it might have something to do with `if search_archive.present?
 _projects = _projects.where(:archive => search_archive == "true")
    end`

Comment: nopes it has ntinh to do with your model code.are you using `get` method to submit the form? if this is the case paster your URL when you checked and unchecked the checkbox

Comment: I have added my urls to the question. I am using `get` method when submitting